# Opening (and Closing) vue material dialog on different components

Tags: vue.js, vue-material

I'm trying to open a vue material dialog on a child component. I want the trigger button to remain on the parent and the dialog box template on a child component so that it would be easier to maintain.

The dialog box opens correctly, but when I click on the close button, the dialog box closes, but I'm unable to open it again with the trigger button. I'm using a prop to pass variables from the parent to the child.

How do I close the dialog box and be able to open it up again?

**app.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="showContextMenu = true">
      <span>Show Context Menu</span>
    </button>
    <contextMenu :showContextMenu="showContextMenu"></contextMenu>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import contextMenu from "contextMenu.vue";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showContextMenu: false,
    };
  },
  components: {
    contextMenu,
  },
};
</script>
```

**contextMenu.vue:**

```
<template>
  <md-dialog :md-active.sync="showContextMenu">
    <md-dialog-title>Preferences</md-dialog-title>Dialog
    <md-dialog-actions>
      <md-button class="md-primary" @click="showContextMenu = false">Close</md-button>
    </md-dialog-actions>
  </md-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  props: ["showContextMenu"],
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing props to child components creates a one way binding, thus you cannot use them to pass state from child to its parent. You can have you `contextMenu` emit an event, on which you change the value of the `showContextMenu` variable in parent. Remember the following: props are used for passing state from parent to child components and events for doing the reverse.

The code would look like this:

app.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="showContextMenu = true">
      <span>Show Context Menu</span>
    </button>
    <contextMenu :showContextMenu="showContextMenu" @close="showContextMenu = false"></contextMenu>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import contextMenu from "contextMenu.vue";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showContextMenu: false,
    };
  },
  components: {
    contextMenu,
  },
};
</script>
```

contextMenu.vue:

```
<template>
  <md-dialog :md-active.sync="showContextMenu">
    <md-dialog-title>Preferences</md-dialog-title>Dialog
    <md-dialog-actions>
      <md-button class="md-primary" @click="$emit('close')">Close</md-button>
    </md-dialog-actions>
  </md-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  props: ["showContextMenu"],
};
</script>
```

Comment: On esc key press, i see this error `[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "active"`

Comment: What about clicking OUTSIDE of the dialog ? the md-overlay sets whatever prop is in md-active.sync to false , even if such prop is not defined locally .

Answer (score 2):

You are actually trying to set a property present in `app`, but you are toggling it false in `contextMenu`.

Mutating prop is never recommended.

Do this instead

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="showContextMenu = true">
      <span>Show Context Menu</span>
    </button>
    <contextMenu v-if="showContextMenu" 
     :showContextMenu="showContextMenu" 
     @close-context="showContextMenu = false"> //capturing event close-context
    </contextMenu>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then in `contextMenu`, emit an event to parent.

**contextMenu.vue**

```
<template>
  <md-dialog :md-active.sync="showContextMenu">
    <md-dialog-title>Preferences</md-dialog-title>Dialog
    <md-dialog-actions>
      <md-button class="md-primary" @click="closeContext">Close</md-button>
    </md-dialog-actions>
  </md-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {
    closeContext() {
      this.$emit('close-context'); // emitting to parent
    },
  props: ["showContextMenu"],
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. You pointed me in the correct direction, although I liked AndrejH's answer better as it saves me some line by writing the $emit method directly inline. Very much appreciated.

Comment: Generally it is recommended to avoid inline function calls. 
In this case, it is just setting a boolean. 
You might want to do some complex stuff and then emit the event with data. 
In that case, inline would be very painful.
Anyway, glad my answer was of help.